# «Не знаю(,) что сказать» — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в выражении «Не знаю(,) что сказать»?

Аккаунт «Современного русского языка» говорит, что нет (https://ask.fm/russian/answers/119848634428) и ссылается на данное правило: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm#_=_

Но в правиле нет именно этой фразы (не перечислено среди неразложимых сочетаний в 1 пункте; в 6 пункте глаголы «быть, найти (найтись), остаться»).

Поэтому у меня возник вопрос, нужна ли здесь запятая в действительности.

Если нужен контекст:

> Это ужасно. Даже не знаю(,) что сказать.

Comment: При чём тут аккаунт?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой аккаунт "Современный русский" на Аск.ФМ -- достаточно авторитетный источник. Его ведут сотрудники просветительского проекта http://www.oshibok-net.ru

Comment: Ясно, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Странно, что аккакунт «Современного русского языка»  так говорит.  Достаточно заглянуть в Нацкорпус, набрать эту фразу и увидеть, что **варианты письма  в практической орфографии** есть (всего там дано 117 примеров). Следовательно, выбор существует. Но, вероятно, они ориентируются на контекст: ***Это ужасно**. Даже не знаю что сказать.*

Это **готовое решение**, но хотелось бы понимать и смысл этого решения.

2. Начнем с того, что Розенталь **не дает полного списка неразложимых сочетаний** – в правилах вы найдете всего лишь типовые примеры.

А вот **ключевая фраза** для решения: «Данное правило основано на том, что фразеологические обороты не образуют придаточного предложения и, как правило, **эквивалентны члену предложения**».  Это общий принцип, который нужно применить к конкретной задаче.

3. Для лучшего понимания рассмотрим **примеры на подобную тему.**
   Вариант 1.  «Что ему сказать, как ты думаешь?»  – «Я не знАю, что сказАть. Решай сама».
   Вариант 2.   «Мне кажется, он что-то скрывает»  – «Даже не знаю что сказАть. Может быть, ты и права».

Смысл вариантов  явно разный. В первом случае глагол «сказать» имеет **прямое значение**, а во втором говорится об отсутствии у собеседника **определенного мнения.** Это становится особенно ясно при использовании частиц «даже, просто».

4. **Интонационно** варианты тоже различаются. В СПП ударение падает и на  опорный глагол «не знаю», и на глагол «сказать» в придаточном предложении, при этом пауза четко обозначена. Это интонация сложного предложения.

Во втором примере ударение падает только на устойчивый оборот, а паузы практически нет. Это интонация простого предложения.

5. Вывод:  Запятая не ставится, это устойчивый оборот: ***Это ужасно. Даже не знаю что сказать.***  Возможная замена: ***Это ужасно, у меня просто слов нет.***

Comment: *Странно, что аккакунт «Современного русского языка» так говорит* - ничего странного. Сомнительный источник, что бы там про него ни говорили.

Comment: Вы так думаете? А вот другие наши участники почему-то считают его авторитетным. Я этот проект плохо знаю, но чисто интуитивно он у меня доверия не вызвал. Много красивых слов, яркой внешности, но вот не помогли они в решении конкретной задачи, так что пользователь обращается за помощью к другим ресурсам.

Answer (score 0):

В п. 1 правила написано **"например"**, а в п. 2 **"типа"**, то есть пункты не
включают исчерпывающие списки.
В списке примеров п. 2 есть выражение *"не нахожу что сказать"*,
по своему типу вполне подобное выражению *"не знаю что
сказать".*

Если проанализировать Нацкорпус, то можно увидеть, что выражение *"не знаю, что сказать"* чаще всего пишется с запятой, но случаи написания без запятой встречаются.

Мне кажется, трудноуловимая разница есть, и она в следующем:

- *Даже не знаю, что сказать* = не знает, как прокомментировать; **буквально** не знает, что сказать;
- *Даже не знаю что сказать* = даже сказать нечего; не в прямом, буквальном смысле "не знаю", а **в переносном**: ужасно, и добавить к этому ничего нельзя.